# Module.js failed to load server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I made a little project using node.js to do a few things with Discord. It worked when I ran it locally with `node server.js` and `npm start`. I decided to put my project online to see if a certain feature worked. When I uploaded it, the main javascript file (server.js) that starts everything wasn't found.

[I just want to be clear that Module.js is not something I made, but part of the node.js built in modules. It's the thing that makes the require function what it is.](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/)

**The error in all it's glory:**

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/openshift/583e028e2d52714d2500041/approot/runtime/repo/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test",
  "scripts": { 
    "start": "node --use_strict server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "keywords": [
    "discord",
  ],
  "author": "kert",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "discord.js": "7.0.0"
  },
  "engines" : {
    "node" : "6.9.1"
  }
}
```

**Structure of files:**

```
Discord
└─── .git
└─── node_modules
└─── rbservers <-nothing is used in this folder
└─── app.js
└─── package.json
└─── server.js
```

If anyone can point out what stupid thing I'm forgetting, pray tell.

My cartridge on OpenShift is the 'Node.js Auto-Updating' one.

Comment: Have you installed all the required dependencies using npm install command?

Comment: have you checked permissions for folders ? and installed all packages

Comment: @AJS Yes. I found both dependencies in my node_modules folder.

Comment: @ManishSingh To be sure, I just reran that command and published to OpenShift. Nothing changed.

Comment: can you show module.js code . On which line exactly you are getting error. And also how you are including the server.js

Comment: Module.js is a built in module that does the job of requiring. It's nothing that I edited or can edit. And the server.js is the start of the app.

Comment: please update with `server.js` and `app.js`

Comment: @SatishPatel Did.

Comment: try `app.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT || 8000,process.env.NODE_IP || '127.0.0.1',init);`

Comment: It won't do anything because process.env.NODE_IP is valid on the server. Also, 0.0.0.0 is better than 127.0.0.1 as it lets you have other computers on the same network access your app.

Comment: instead of `process.env.NODE_IP` use `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` for `app.listen` this might work just try and check as per Openshift docs.

Comment: @SatishPatel Sadly, that didn't work. Still having the same module.js error.

Comment: how are you pushing to git? use after * in `git add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, git wasn't staging/committing all the files in order for them to be pushed. I'll have to look around on how to fix this.

Ugh.

Comment: fixed by `git add *`